# VC++ 2010 MySQL Some Errors

Tags: c++, mysql

I have Visual Studio 10 c++, MySQL connectors and Server.

My code is:

```
 #include "mysql_connection.h"
 #include "mysql_driver.h"
 #include <cppconn/driver.h>
 #include <cppconn/exception.h>
 #include <cppconn/resultset.h>
 #include <cppconn/statement.h>
 #include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
 void main()
    {
      sql::Driver *driver;
      sql::Connection *con;
      sql::Statement *stmt;
      sql::ResultSet *res;
      sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;
      con = driver->connect("localhost","root","admin12");
    }
```

If i compile with debug give me that error:

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'driver' is being used without being initialized.

---

And if i compile with release give me that:

> Excepción no controlada en 0x003610db en MySQL.exe: 0xC0000005: Infracción de acceso al leer la ubicación 0x0fc08561.

---

Give me errors in line

```
con = driver->connect("localhost","root","admin12");
```

Help?

Comment: Did you read the error message? *"The variable is being used without being initialized."* sounds pretty obvious - you did not set this variable to any meaningful value before using it.

Comment: How I can do?, I'm bad in C++ S:

Comment: [How to use MySQL Connector/C++](http://r3dux.org/2010/11/how-to-use-mysql-connectorc-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-windows/).

Comment: It seems you need to read a tutorial on basic C++ _before_ trying to something like connecting to a database.

Comment: I nnever thought Id say that in here, but please go learn C++. You dont seem to know shit

Answer (score 1):

Other people using MySQL connectors seem to write code like this

```
sql::Driver *driver; 
driver = get_driver_instance();
```

and then the `driver` variable is no longer uninitialzed.

Comment: Give me that errors:

Error 1 error LNK2001: símbolo externo __imp__get_driver_instance sin resolver A:\LoginServer\LoginServer\main.obj LoginServer


Error 2 error LNK2001: símbolo externo "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall sql::SQLException::~SQLException(void)" (__imp_??1SQLException@sql@@UAE@XZ) sin resolver A:\LoginServer\LoginServer\main.obj LoginServer